# Display a list of dictionnary with kivy

Tags: python, list, dictionary, kivy

I'm scraping data from ESPN with this code:

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'http://www.espn.com/nba/team/schedule/_/name/bos'  

r = requests.get(url)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

listes = soup.find_all('ul', class_='game-schedule') 

resultats = []
i = 0
for liste in listes :

    if not i % 2 :
        resultat = {}

    for item in liste.find_all('li') :
        if item.text :
            if 'class' in item.attrs :
                cle = str(item.attrs['class'][-1])
                if cle in ('win', 'loss') :
                    cle = 'resultat'
                resultat[cle] = item.text 

    if i % 2 and 'score' in resultat.keys() :
        resultats.append(resultat)
    i += 1

print(resultats)
```

It prints the results of last game of Celtics into a list of dictionaries. The problem is that I want to display it with Kivy, but I can't succeed in it by trying:

```
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.base import runTouchApp


class MainView(ListView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(
            resultats)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(MainView())
```

It shows me this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView    
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

class MainView(ListView): 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(item_strings=resultats)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(MainView())
```

can you try above snippet, hope this helps

Comment: On the way ! now it opens a window , but it remains white , the error is :ValueError: Label.text accept only str

Comment: then you have yo verify your `resultats` list, check whether it's same as you expect.
hope you got your answer, please accept it as the correct answer

Comment: what do you mean by as i expect ?

Comment: `resultats` looks like a list of list of strings, make it a list of strings

Comment: but how can i convert that into a list of strings ?                                             [{'score': '106-102', 'resultat': 'L', 'game-status': 'vs', 'team-name': 'Chicago'}, {'score': '111-97', 'resultat': 'L', 'game-status': 'vs', 'team-name': 'Chicago'}, {'score': '104-87', 'resultat': 'W', 'game-status': '@', 'team-name': 'Chicago'}...]

Comment: which values you want to show in your listview, if your single entry corresponds to all values from `{'score': '106-102', 'resultat': 'L', 'game-status': 'vs', 'team-name': 'Chicago'}`, then you can create a string with some delimiter

Comment: but how can i do that , how can i separe score from 106-102 for example?

Comment: they need not be separated, for eg: "106-102, L, vs, Chicago", this would be a single entry

Answer (score 0):

It's true what pramod says that separation isn't exactly necessary in this case. But you may someday actually want to do it, and you can. There are many ways to get it done, here is one off the top of my head. It's probably not the most efficient way to do it, but it works.

```
import re
mydict = [  {'score': '106-102', 'resultat': 'L', 'game-status': 'vs', 'team-name': 'Chicago'}, 
            {'score': '111-97', 'resultat': 'L', 'game-status': 'vs', 'team-name': 'Chicago'}, 
            {'score': '104-87', 'resultat': 'W', 'game-status': '@', 'team-name': 'Chicago'}]
for i in  range(len(mydict)):
    tempdict = list(dict(mydict[i]).values())
    for x in range(len(tempdict)):
        if re.search('\d',tempdict[x]):
            print(tempdict[x])
```

The results:
    106-102
    111-97
    104-87